# How to enable Virtualization technology in Samsung Chromebox

Tags: bios, virtualization, linux-kvm, google-chrome-os, vt-x

I need to enable Virtualization Technology (VT) in my Samsung Chromebox (Series 5) from Google IO 2012 because of Android x86 emulator from Intel. I am on developer BIOS, but I have no clue, how to modify its settings. Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: It would be advisable to detail in your post what exactly you are doing and in which environment with much more detail.

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the Samsung Chromebox Series 3, the CPU is Intel® Celeron™ Processor B840.

Unfortunately, **this cpu doesn't support VT-d.**

Comment: That CPU doesn't support VT-d (directed I/O), but it DOES support VT-x. See [Intel's ARK entry on it](http://ark.intel.com/products/59801/Intel-Celeron-Processor-B840-2M-Cache-1_90-GHz).

Comment: No, I am talking about Series 5.