# How to enable virtualization on samsung 300E4A/300E5A/300E7A/3430EA/3530EA

Tags: virtualization, android-studio, hardware-acceleration

Im running android studio. However when I try to debug I get the following:

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Now I know virtualization needs to be enabled. I checked the machine config using hwinfo and it says that the machine supports virtualization but it isn't enabled. I went into the bios but cannot find a setting to enable it. Any ideas how i can enable virtualization?

Comment: If the option to enable it isn't in the BIOS then it cannot be enabled.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/475685/how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-in-samsung-chromebox?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Go to UEFI Advanced mode->Advanced tab->CPU Configuration-> Intel Virtualization Technology.

This assumes the CPU types that comes with the notebooks do support virtualization (be warned that some celerons do not support it).

Comment: Have you confirmed this option exists within the UEFI configuration since the author seems to indicate it does not.

Comment: On some UEFIs the advanced tab (or other tabs) is (are) beyond visible screen and you have to scroll sideways in order to see them.